# How to group date by quarter in mysql and retrieve in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains product orders and the date they were ordered. The date was inserted into the table using DATE(). The customers can get a statistic of these orders by choosing to view by month, quarterly, yearly or total. I need to retrieve every order since the beginning so there is no start date, only end date (today) and they need to be sorted.

So, if they select quarterly, (the database starts in 2006), then it needs to display every order from 2006, quarterly and then with PHP, I need to display it like so:

Quarter 1 - 2006

---

date , product1, quantity, price
date , product2, quantity, price

Quarter 2 - 2006

---

date , product1, quantity, price
date , product2, quantity, price

.
.
.

Quarter 1 - 2014

---

date , product1, quantity, price
date , product2, quantity, price

Is there a way to sort it like that? I can add things like quantity, price and product name myself. I'm interested in figuring out how to sort the dates like that when the field in the database was populated using DATE (). I hope the question is clear enough. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863734/sql-how-group-by-fiscal-quarter-and-year-with-a-date-field
You should get the idea from this post

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using mySQL's QUARTER(date) function? If you want to sort after your retrieval rather than during it, add a column to your output and populate it with QUARTER(date), and then sort by that column.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to figure out a starting point first

```
select YEAR(date_column) as min_year, QUARTER(date_column) as min_quarter from table order by date_column limit 1;
```

then you can do the printing in PHP starting from that index:

```
for($i=$min_year; $i <= date('Y'); $i++){
    for($j=$min_quarter; $j<=ceiling(date('m')); $j++){
        echo "Quarter $j - $i";
        mysql_query("SELECT date, product, quantity, price FROM table WHERE QUARTER(date)=$j and YEAR(date)=$i ORDER BY date");
        //print your rows
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```